# Change icon on li click?

Tags: html, list, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have:

- A list (UL,LI) with Bootstrap icon
- Search bar with icon and an  field.

I want that when I click on list item, then the related icon should be placed on top, and that should repeat with all (list items).

Here is the **[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/IHvFWp0ieZ)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a click event to `ul li` and get the class on the clicked element.
Then apply the same class to the search bar icon element. 
Like this..

```
$('.searchlink ul li').click(function(){
   var className = $(this).find('.glyphicon').attr("class");
   $(".searcati").find("span.glyphicon").attr("class", className);
   $(".searchlink").slideToggle("slow");
   return false;
});
```

Updated bootply : http://www.bootply.com/Fp6zfoiIZr